# Solving angles in a parallelogram with multiple variables

Tags: geometry

[image: Parallelogram Problem]

I have a Math test tomorrow, and was going over the study guide. I have solved problems like this before with elimination, but this one confused me. I have not learned trig(sin,cos,tan) so this problem is meant to be solved by knowing the properties of parallelograms. If anyone could help me, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TIP**: $\rm m\angle J + \rm m\angle K = \rm m\angle K + \rm m\angle L = 180°$

Comment: Misread, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: I got x=15, and y=10. Your tip really helped me!

Comment: Please consider upvoting it and selecting as the correct answer :)

Comment: I am new to this site, so It says it won't show it publicly, but "is recorded"